# How to determine if string is of type int or double, to used in overload method? C#

Tags: c#, overloading, string-conversion

I want to call an overload method using the value that was inserted into my texbox. By default it is of value string, so I have to check if it is of type int or double. 
I am using the TryParse() to check and see if the values are of either int or double, but it causes me to have 2 variables for each textbox. I only want the 2 variables that has been successful. 
I do not know how to determine which has been successful so that I can use them in the overload method call.

My code looks like this...

```
        string a = textBox1.Text, b = textBox2.Text;
        int f;
        double d;
        if(int.TryParse(a, out f))
        {
        }
        else if(double.TryParse(a, out d))
        {
        }
        int s;
        double sD;
        if (int.TryParse(b, out s))
        {
        }
        else if(double.TryParse(b, out sD))
        {
        }
        double x;
        //Do not know which values to pass, because i only want the 2 
        //that was successful
        Area(?, ?, out x);
        label3.Text = "This is the value " + x;
    }
    private static void Area(int a, int b, out double x)
    {
        x = a * b;
    }
    private static void Area(double a, double b, out double x)
    {
        x = a * b;
    }
    private static void Area(int a, double b, out double x)
    {
        x = a * b;
    }
```

If I then nest the if else statements, the compiler gives me an error saying that the double value is unassigned. I know a bunch of if else statements are ugly code, but it is the only way I currently know how.

```
        if(f == '\0' && s == '\0')
        { Area(d, sD, out sum); }
        else if(d=='\0' && s=='\0')
        {Area(f, sD, out sum;)}
        //and so on...
```

Comment: Given the logic is the same, why bother with the `int` implementation? Why not always use the `double` (middle) one? _Also, don't use `void` and `out` parameters like that - instead just `return a * b;`._

Comment: The practice I am doing demands that is use an overload method with double and int. Otherwise I would have only used double.

Comment: It is to clearly understand how overload methods work, and everything apart with it. It is a book I am working through.

Comment: Be sure to use the right terminology. A string value will always be of type *string*, never of type *int* or *double*. What you're talking about is a string value that contains the string representation of a number, either a whole number which can be parsed into an int, or a floating point number which can be parsed into a double. Also, do you need the distinction? doubles can also represent whole numbers.

Comment: There isn't really a nice way to do this but that is largely as it isn't a nice thing to do. mjwills has the right of it that you should just use double and forget about ints but given you want to detect your ints and doubles then the only thing I can think to do is to have some bools to determine which conversions you want to use (eg `bool value1IsInt`) and then have a nasty looking four branch if/elseif statement to determine which overload you want to call.

Comment: Does the out parameter not already support null, because it is a reference type? And we only got introduced, did not really cover it.

Comment: @ChristoffelJoubert: What do you think is a reference type? `int` and `double` are both value types and cannot be null. `int.TryParse` and `double.TryParse` will both set the out value to `0` in the event they cannot successfully parse.

Comment: I have tried creating the a single var value that can be used in both if else statements out value, but the compiler wont let me. i thought that if I create a var of int that the double parse call would work, because a double can be an int.

Comment: I think you have it the wrong way round, a double can't be an int (eg 1.5 is not an int). This is basically what was originally suggested though of just using doubles and ignoring parsing as an int.

Comment: The TryParse() does return null if it was not successful, but if I insert it into a nested if else statement like so.

Comment: @ChristoffelJoubert you could cast a `double` to an `int`, but you would lose precision (no decimals in integers.). you could do it the other way around without losing any data.

Comment: @ChristoffelJoubert in the example you gave, `TryParse` returns either `true`, or `false`, depending on whether it could successfully parse the provided string. if it can parse the provided input, it will assign the parsed value to the variable referenced with `out`. if it can't parse the value, it will leave the `out` variable alone.

Comment: if i nest the if else statements, the compiler gives me an error saying my double values are unassigned?

Comment: if(f == '\0' && s == '\0')
            { Area(d, sD, out sum); }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest form i can come up with is putting the TryParses in sequence in a single `if` statement and, handling the first one that succeeds.

This leaves the possibility that one string cannot be parsed (or neither), so in that case i am throwing an exception

```
int intA;
int intB;

double doubleA;
double doubleB;
double x;

if(int.TryParse(a, out intA) && int.TryParse(b, out intB))
{
   Area(intA, intB, out x);
}
else if (double.TryParse(a, out doubleA) && double.TryParse(b, out doubleB))
{
   Area(doubleA, doubleB, out x);
}
else
{
   throw new ArgumentException("cannot parse one or both numbers");
}

label3.Text = "This is the value " + x;
```

Comment: This doesn't cover the scenario where a or b is parsable as an int and the other only as a double (ie there is one overload that you aren't calling).

Comment: Your approach will work, it just needs to be extended with two more cases ("a int, b double" and "a double, b int"). It won't be pretty but that's to be expected given the OP's convoluted requirements...

Comment: I think OP's book could use some work if it's creating these kinds of problems to illustrate the need for something as relatively simple as overloading. it's also setting a bad example since it's a bad solution to this problem to begin with.

Comment: Absolutely 100% agree. As long as the OP reads comments though then they should be aware of this at least... :)

Comment: Thank you i just needed to put both arguments in the same if statement and nest all the possibilities. Not as pretty, but it was for sake of practice. Much appreciated.